# How can I use jQuery to submit a form via ajax and parse the response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, es6-promise

I have simplified my code to only show the relevant code for this example.  I can submit the form just fine but I need to learn how I can get the response when there is an error so I can parse it and display the error.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
        $.ajax( URL, {
            'data': data,
            'method': 'PUT'
            }
        }),
        .done( function() {
            // yay!
        })
        .fail( function() {
            // How can I get the failure response and parse this?
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you read the docs and look at what the arguments are?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourFormButton', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();// catch the form's submit event
        var one = $('#yourvalueone').val();
        var two = $('#yourvaluetwo').val();
        var three = $('#yourvaluethree').val();


                    $.ajax({url: 'YourScript.php',
                        data:  {one:one,two:two,three:three },
                        type: 'post',                   
                        async: 'true',
                        //dataType: 'jsonp',//can specify type we will return html
                        beforeSend: function() { //catch before send maybe load spinner

                            console.log('before');
                        },
                        complete: function(data) { //capture complete

                            console.log('complete');


                        },
                        success: function (data) {//it successful place returned HTML from PHP script in DIV
                            $('#DivForYourResults').html(data);

                        }
                    });
                });
```

Send it to your php script and just echo "hello" this will be returned to your page. Then try putting the data into the database etc

Comment: Hmm.  It's not using the .fail( function() ) and also not parsing any responses for errors.

Comment: You can add them as parameters.

Comment: @sjmartin just add error: in the same way that success: , complete:  is added. There are many more detailed parameters http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/